# I have a keyboard that always comes up at unrecognized. Can I disable osx from telling me?

Tags: keyboard

The keyboard is the new typematrix 2030 http://typematrix.com/

When I plug the keyboard in it always shows up as unrecognized and is unable to figure out what type of keyboard it is based on pressing the key directly to the right of the left shift and directly to the left of the right shift.

Can I tell osx not to bother me about unrecognized keyboards or to remember this one for the future?

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be a proper kernel extension provided by the vendor or someone else.

I can tell you what can't help: ControllerMate, KeyRemap4MacBook, Secrets or some other utility for hidden settings, nor USB Overdrive last time I checked.

You could try to ask around those devs if anyone wants to get famous a little.

My present incarnation of that issue: some Logitech and MS mouses(!) manage to trigger that dialog! Logitech even admits it, saying 'just dismiss it'. The drivers they provide are not totally satisfying yet, to quote Colonel Panic's words.

Comment: The vendor really has to work with Apple to either provide Apple with the details of their keyboards so that ships with the OS or provide a file (hopefully less than a kernel extension) to let OS X automagically recognize their hardware so the key layout works when hot plugged.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use some third party drivers? [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/)?